# Slide Bottom TabBar to right/left when the drawer is open

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'am trying to slide bottom TabBar when the drawer is open ,And it's only slides the header

Drawer:

```
 const SilderNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home : HomeStackNavigator ,
},
{
  contentComponent : MenuContentComponent ,
  drawerType : "slide" ,
})
```

TabBar:

```
const BottomBarNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator({
  home: SilderNavigator,
  notification: NotificaStack
  ... })
```

StackNavigator to wrap navigator's together:

```
const BaseNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  BottomBarNavigation : BottomBarNavigation,
  Details : {screen : Details, ...}
  ... })
```

Comment: can you explain more? Do you wan to hide bottomTabs when drawer is open?

Comment: not hiding... slide the whole screen to right include bottom TabBar and the Header

Comment: not able to understand please provide more information on this, if you have what you want to make then that will help to understand better